# Creating a DELETE script based on a SELECT script

Tags: sql, plsql, crystal-reports, sql-delete

Fairly new to PL/SQL...

I have the following **SELECT** script which joins two different tables to get the output I require.

I also have a **WHERE** clause within the sub-query which looks at two separate conditions:

```
    SELECT p.provider_id, p.prov_name, ecp.*
  FROM ey30h_check_provider ecp
  JOIN provider p
    ON ecp.provider_id = p.provider_id
  JOIN ey30h_check ec
    ON ecp.ey30h_check_id = ec.ey30h_check_id
 WHERE (ecp.ey30h_check_id, ec.dern_number) IN
       (select ec.ey30h_check_id, ec.dern_number
          from ey30h_check ec
         WHERE ec.dern_number = '52365214587'
           AND ecp.provider_id = 50014);
```

Results to this script can be seen below:

[image: Results from SELECT script]

How would I go about creating a **DELETE** script for this?

I've tried having a little dig at it with the following script, but this displays '**ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined**':

```
DELETE from ey30h_check_provider ecp
WHERE ecp.ey30h_check_id in 
(select ec.ey30h_check_id from ey30h_check ec
JOIN ey30h_check ec ON ecp.ey30h_check_id = ec.ey30h_check_id
JOIN provider p ON ecp.provider_id = p.provider_id
WHERE ec.dern_number = '52365214587'
AND ecp.provider_id = 50014);
```

Fairly new to PL/SQL so any advise will be appreciated :)

Comment: first, remove the delete clause and run the select query. if run time occurred any error so put in the problem statement.

Comment: In the SELECT part you've aliased ey30h_check as ec twice,

Comment: @OTTA I noticed I accidentally had duplicate join statements, therefore have removed this.

@Kiran

`SELECT * from ey30h_check_provider ecp
WHERE ecp.ey30h_check_id in 
(select ec.ey30h_check_id, ec.dern_number from ey30h_check ec
JOIN ey30h_check ec ON ecp.ey30h_check_id = ec.ey30h_check_id
JOIN provider p ON ecp.provider_id = p.provider_id
WHERE ec.dern_number = '52365214587'
AND ecp.provider_id = 50014);`


The above script outputs: ORA-00913: too many values

Comment: Looks like you can do this without PL/SQL, just using a plain DELETE statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this:

```
DELETE from ey30h_check_provider ecp
WHERE ecp.ey30h_check_id in
    (SELECT ecp.ey30h_check_id
    FROM ey30h_check_provider ecp
    JOIN provider p
    ON ecp.provider_id = p.provider_id
    JOIN ey30h_check ec
    ON ecp.ey30h_check_id = ec.ey30h_check_id
    JOIN provider p
    ON ecp.provider_id = p.provider_id
        WHERE (ecp.ey30h_check_id, ec.dern_number) IN
        (select ec.ey30h_check_id, ec.dern_number from ey30h_check ec
            WHERE ec.dern_number = '52365214587'
            AND ecp.provider_id = 50014));
```

**'ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined':**  occurs when, a column name used in a join exists in more than one table and is thus referenced ambiguously. In a join, any column name that occurs in more than one of the tables must be prefixed by its table name when referenced. The column should be referenced as TABLE.COLUMN or TABLE_ALIAS.COLUMN.

If your select query gives correct output, your delete query shouldn't give you any problem.